# Symfony3 Docs WSSE fail "Cannot replace arguments if none have been configured yet"

Tags: symfony, wsse

Following this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Results in

> Service "security.authentication.provider.wsse.wsse_secured": Cannot replace arguments if none have been configured yet.

I cannot find anything about this error anywhere. This uses the doc's WSSE code and it fails.

This repo shows it failing https://github.com/jakenoble/wsse_test

I want to get it working eventually with the FOS User Bundle. But I cannot get it to work with a basic Symfony3 install so FOS User Bundle is out of the question at the moment.

Having dug around a bit...

There is a an arg at element `index_0` on class `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ChildDefinition` the object for the arg at element `index_0` has an id of `fos_user.user_provider.username_email`.

The replace call then attempts to get the arguments of `fos_user.user_provider.username_email`, but there are none. Then the error occurs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** Move your service definitions below the autoloading definitions in `services.yml` and change the `WsseFactory` code to

```
    $container
        ->setDefinition($providerId, new ChildDefinition(WsseProvider::class))
        ->setArgument('$userProvider', new Reference($userProvider))
    ;
```

**Full explanation.**
The first mistake in the supplied code is that the services definitions prepend the autoloading lines. The autoloading will just override the previous definitions and will cause the `AuthenticationManagerInterface` failure. Moving the definitions below will fix the issue. The other way to fix the issue is aliases as @yceruto and @gintko pointed.

But only that move will not make the code work despite on your answer. You probably didnt notice how changed something else to make it work.

The second issue, the failure of `replaceArgument`, is related to Symfony's order of the container compilation as was correctly supposed. The order is defined in the `PassConfig` class:

```
$this->optimizationPasses = array(array(
        new ExtensionCompilerPass(),
        new ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass(),
        ...
        $autowirePass = new AutowirePass(false),
        ...
    ));
```

I omitted the irrelevant passes. The `security.authentication.provider.wsse.wsse_secured` definition created by the `WsseFactory` is produced first. Then `ResolveDefinitionTemplatesPass` will take place, and will try to replace the arguments of the definition and raise the `Cannot replace arguments` exception you got:

```
    foreach ($definition->getArguments() as $k => $v) {
        if (is_numeric($k)) {
            $def->addArgument($v);
        } elseif (0 === strpos($k, 'index_')) {
            $def->replaceArgument((int) substr($k, strlen('index_')), $v);
        } else {
            $def->setArgument($k, $v);
        }
    }
```

The issue will appear cause the pass will call `Definition::replaceArgument` for `index_0`. As the parent definition doesn't have an argument at position 0 neither in the former `services.xml` nor in the fixed one. `AutowirePass` wasn't executed yet, the autogenerated definitions has no arguments, the manual definition has the named `$cachePool` argument only.

So to fix the issue you could use rather:

```
->setArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider)); //proposed by @yceruto
->replaceArgument('$userProvider', new Reference($userProvider)); //proposed by @gintko
->setArgument('$userProvider', new Reference($userProvider)); // by me
```

All of them will entail the calls of `Definition::addArgument` or `Definition::setArgument` and will work out. There are only the little difference:
- `setArgument(0, ...` could not work for some other scenarios;
- I like `->setArgument('$userProvider'` more than `->replaceArgument('$userProvider'` due to semantics. Nothing to replace yet!

Hope the details why the issue appears now clear.

**PS.** There are also few other funny ways to overcome the issue.

Fix the config a bit:

```
AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider:
    arguments:
        0: ''
        $cachePool: '@cache.app'
    public: false
```

Or set an alias of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface` to let the autowire do the rest for you.

```
    $container
        ->setDefinition($providerId, new ChildDefinition(WsseProvider::class))
    //    ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
    ;
    $container
        ->setAlias('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface',$userProvider)
    ;
```

Answer (score 4):

This look like at this moment the provider definition doesn't have the autowired arguments ready, maybe related to the order in which the "CompilerPass" are processed, by now you can solve it with these little tweaks:

change this line in `WsseFactory.php`:

```
->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
```

by:

```
->setArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
```

and add this alias to `services.yml` to complete the autowired arguments of the new provider:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface: '@security.authentication.manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** (deleted the previous contents due to the comment)

I see you don't use FOSUserBundle that makes things more comples.  I did not yet create PR.

I think you are missing [custom user entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html). (see the link I have provided to create your own entity - my PR would be similar to these lines, if you are unable to create your own entity using my description and the link I'll provide PR, but that will take longer).

The steps you have to take:

1. Create your own User entity via `src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php`
2. Create DB table via `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
3. Configure `Security` to load your `Entity` - `use AppBundle\Entity\User;`
4. Then you have to create your own user.  This can be tricky see [password encoding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html) for more.
5. (optional) Forbid interactive users If you want to login using
6. username OR email you can create `Custom Query to Load the User`

These steps should be enough for you to create your own user Entity and you don't have to use the FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Did you pull that repo and attempt to fix it? Because nothing in your answer would affect the basic implementation from the repo. I have a version which uses FOS User Bundle, but it doesn't work. It has the config in place already.

Comment: @JakeN: please see my edit.  I have changed the answer completely.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Ok, so read some source code, and in [`ChildDefinition:100`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ChildDefinition.php#L100) you can see, that arguments are also indexed by argument's `$name`. So, it must be, that at compile time arguments of autowired services are passed with their named indexes, instead of numbered indexes.

`WsseFactory.php`

```
->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider));
```

so argument should be referenced by it's name:

```
->replaceArgument('$userProvider', new Reference($userProvider));
```

After this change, you will get new exception error, which says that it's not possible to autowire `$authenticationManager` in `WsseListener` service by it's interface. You can fix it simply by specifying alias for that interface in your `services.yml`:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface: '@security.authentication.manager'
```

---

<strike>I guess this issue is related with new `autowire` feature, I will try to investigate it later why it is so.</strike>

For now, you can use old way to define services:

services.yml:

```
app.security.wsse_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider
        arguments:
            - ''
            - '@cache.app'
        public: false

app.security.wsse_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Firewall\WsseListener
    arguments: ['@security.token_storage', '@security.authentication.manager']
    public: false
```

in WsseFactory.php, following lines:

```
new ChildDefinition(WsseFactory::class);
new ChildDefinition(WsseListener::class);
```

translates into:

```
new ChildDefinition('app.security.wsse_provider');
new ChildDefinition('app.security.wsse_listener');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is because my config in services.yml came before the new auto wiring stuff.

So simply moving it below the auto wiring fixes it.

Comment: Sure? I tried moving it below the autowiring config and the problem persists

Comment: That fixed it for me, am I using it now